# Append text to <option> inner html in Formstastic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I have two tables: groups and series. A serie `has_many` groups and a group `belongs_to` a serie.
I'm using Formstastic to automatically generate a `<select>` with all the series so the user will be able to select the serie related to the group being created.
But a serie `belongs_to` the table units, which `has_many` series. Since series have the same name, it will not possible for the user to know exactly which serie he's choosing in the `<select>`, unless he knows to which unit a specific serie belongs to. For that I'd like every `<option>` to have the following format:

`<option value="serie_id">serie.name – unit.name</option>`

What I have until now (and working) is:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Group" do       
        f.input :serie
        f.input :name
    end                               
  f.actions                         
  end 
end
```

Any other suggestion on how to achieve my goal (specifying exactly the serie related to the unit) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# in controller
@custom_collection = Serie.all.map{ |s| ["#{s.name} - #{s.unit.name}", s.id]}

# in view
f.input :serie, collection: options_for_select(@custom_collection)
```

This code assumes that a Serie always have a Unit associated. It will raise an error if not. Use the following if you want to show the unit name only if it exists:

```
@custom_collection = Serie.all.map do |serie|
  composed_name = s.name
  composed_name += " - #{s.unit.name}" if s.unit.present?
  [composed_name, s.id]
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! In my case, a Serie will always have a unit, so the first solution works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can add a method to your Serie model as:

```
def fomatted_name
  name + unit.name # if you have an association belongs_to :unit
end
```

And in your view:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Group" do       
      f.input :serie, :label_method => :formatted_name, :as => :select
      f.input :name
    end                               
    f.actions                         
  end 
end
```

Comment: That did not work but was actually a good hint. When showing the results I needed to create a method in Group model, but was a little different:

`def unit
   serie.unit
  end`